# How to find a mapping to a higher dimension that separates the data, given a data set

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, linear, kernel-trick, separation

We have the following dataset:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
x_1 & x_2 & y\\ 
+1 & 0 & +1\\ 
-1 & 0 & +1\\ 
0 & +2 & +1\\ 
0 & +1 & -1
\end{bmatrix} $$

I was asked to find a mapping $\varphi$ to any dimension such that in the new dimension this data will become linear separable, and find this linear separator.

I really don't know how to solve those type of questions, and any help about it will be amazing!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**An example approach**

Plot the points on a 2D axis. You have +1's on the x-axis at $x_1=1$ and $x_1=-1$. You have another +1 on $x_2=1$, but a -1 on $x_2=1$ on the y-axis. Now, you ponder about the curves that can be drawn to isolate the -1.

Line is not possible as can be seen by visual inspection. A parabola pointing down seems possible, if the parabola's head was between $x_2\in [1,2]$ and arms cross the x-axis at around some $x_1$ satisfying $|x_1|<1$.

Let's say we mark the middle points, i.e. $(0,1.5), (0.5, 0), (-0.5,0)$.

A parabola has the formula $x_2=ax_1^2+bx_1+c$. When above passing points are substituted into this general formula, we find
$$x_2=-6x_1^2+1.5$$

So, a mapping $\psi(x_1,x_2)=6x_1^2+x_2-1.5$ would produce separate the data after taking the sign.

**Another approach**

Seems like we can decide based on $x_2$ only. When it is $0$ or $2$, label is +1; when it is $1$, label is $-1$. A simple formula for this would be $(x_2-1)^2-0.5$. This is mostly intuition.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you so much!